# NullPointerException while cloning a graph using DFS iteratively

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I am trying to clone a graph using `DFS` in `Java` `iteratively`, but on compiling it keeps on showing `NullPointerException`. I know the code using `recursion` is uch simpler, but wanted to try out in `iterative` way.
The code is shown below:

```
 /**
 * Definition for undirected graph.
 * class UndirectedGraphNode {
 *     int label;
 *     List<UndirectedGraphNode> neighbors;
 *     UndirectedGraphNode(int x) { label = x; neighbors = new ArrayList<UndirectedGraphNode>(); }
 * };
 */

public UndirectedGraphNode cloneGraph(UndirectedGraphNode node) {
    if(node==null) return null;
    Map<UndirectedGraphNode, UndirectedGraphNode> hm = new HashMap<>();
    Stack<UndirectedGraphNode> st = new Stack<>();
    st.push(node);

    while(!st.isEmpty())
    {
        UndirectedGraphNode n = st.pop(); 
        UndirectedGraphNode copy = null;
        if(!hm.containsKey(n)) //if n is cloned before, no need to clone it again
        {
            copy = new UndirectedGraphNode(n.label); //clone parent
            hm.put(n, copy);
        }
        else
            copy = hm.get(n); 

        for(UndirectedGraphNode neighbor: n.neighbors)
        {
            if(!hm.containsKey(neighbor))
            {
                UndirectedGraphNode copy_neighbor = new UndirectedGraphNode(neighbor.label);
                copy.neighbors.add(copy_neighbor); //clone child.
                hm.put(neighbor, copy_neighbor);
                st.push(neighbor);
            }else
                copy.neighbors.add(hm.get(neighbor));//this handles parent node as well.
        }

    }
    return hm.get(node);   
}
```

Here, what I am tryig to do is get a node from the graph and traverse to it's next connected node or as in this case `neighbor`.

The `NullPointerException` is being shown in this line :

```
copy.neighbors.add(copy_neighbor);
```

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at line 55, Solution.cloneGraph
at line 102, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: You may want to ensure that `copy` and `copy.neighbors` are not null.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace and mark the line that throws it.

Comment: @c0der, added the `exception stacktrace` and also I have pointed where the `nullpointer exception` occurs

Comment: So use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to find which variable is null, or simply add printouts before that line to check `System.out.println(copy==null);`  and `System.out.println(copy.neighbors==null);`

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not initialing the `neighbors` attribute on the `UndirectedGraphNode` class. Make sure you initialize, either on the attribute declaration:

```
private List<UndirectedGraphNode> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or in the constructor:

```
public UndirectedGraphNode(String label) {
   ...
   neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Already done. I have updated the question